# SQL Server 2016 : need to rank attributes of char type from different tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a small db for a college SQL class project. The database is a collection of information regarding scuba training.

I have a table which is CLASS and has a column IREQ char(2). This is a list of classes and the IREQ column is the instructor type required for that class.

Another table is INST with a column INSTYPE char(2). This is a table of instructor information and the INSTYPE column is the instructors current type.
A third table is ITITLE with three columns; TNUM int, TITLE varchar (40), TABR char(2). TNUM is sequential numbers for each row for ranking. TITLE is the full name of each trainer level. TABR is the two character abbreviation of the TITLE and corresponds to INSTYPE and IREQ in the previous tables.

I need to check which instructors have a high enough trainer level to teach a given set of courses for a given month.

I have the Class selection and month with

```
where 
    CNUMBER like 'SD____'
    and 7 = month(STARTDATE)
```

The SELECT command includes each instructors First/Alias/Last names, Instructor Number, Class Number, Class Name, Start Date

From all three tables.

I've tried a subquery within a subquery but get an error requiring an 'exists' statement after the where.

I've tried a few other things but can't get the conversion to a number value for ranking comparison. I only have the 2 character field, that is an abbreviation for the title, that is common between all three tables but can't be a foreign key (that I can see). The only thing I can think of is to somehow set a value for the IREQ or TNUM fields equal to the TNUM value for the matching TABR field. THE ITITLE table is exactly 8 rows and the TABR are not in alphabetical order relative to the TNUM value. I made the table exclusively to assign a number to the TABR so I could do this and a similar comparison between another set of tables.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question and add few dozen rows of sample data and your expected result based on that data.

Comment: `--Create the table for scuba classes
Create Table CLASS
(CNUMBER char(6) primary key,
CNAME varchar(40) not null,
STARTDATE date,
DUR int,
SCHED varchar(10),
PREREQ varchar(6),
INUM char(10),
IREQ char(2) not null);`   `--Create a table for Instructors Information including
--training level and any restrictions or limits.
Create Table INST
(INUM int primary key,
INSLNAME varchar(25) not null,
INSFNAME varchar(20) not null,
INSNNAME varchar(25),
INSTYPE char(2),
INSSPECIALS varchar(50);`

Comment: `--Create a table that codifies current instructor title
--to a level value for comparison actions.
Create table ITITLE
(TNUM int(1) primary key,
TITLE varchar(40) not null,
TABR char(2) not null);`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting in the comments. First time posting.

Comment: These are the create table statements I used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using with the windows functions in SQL
https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the source of STARTDATE nor the CNUMBER, you can adapt this to your needs (add the where clause and update the columns you need):

```
select c.*, t1.*, i.* 
from     CLASS   c 
    join ITITLE t1 on  c.IREQ  = t1.TABR
    join ITITLE t2 on t1.TNUM <= t2.TNUM
    join INST    i on t2.TABR  =  i.INSTYPE
```

This will list every class with every instructor with high enough rank to teach it.

Comment: This may work. I can't get to it until tomorrow. There are several more select attributes for names, etc as noted above. The CNUMBER and STARTDATE columns are both in the CLASS table.

Comment: Would I use your suggestion as a subquery or the main query to include the remainig information from the CLASS table? Or simply add the needed SELECT attributes at the top, then the WHERE clause after the last join?

Comment: Also, just for clarity for my understanding, The first join is an inner join on the CLASS table and ITITLE table where IREQ =TABR and this is a character comparison. The third join links the INSTYPE to the ITITLE table.So then the Second join is a self join between the TNUM from the first join, and the TNUM from the third join? The first/third compare char sets and the second compares int values(rank)?

Comment: On your second comment - as written, the select statement will retrun all columns from the CLASS table, all columns from the ITITLE (related to the class) and all columns from the INST table. If you want only specific columns, list them one by one: select c.CNAME, c.STARTDATE, ..., t1.TITLE 'Class Rank', t2.TITLE 'Instructor Rank', ...

Comment: On your third comment, you are on the right track. Provided the ITITLE.TABR is unique, the first join is one to one so it doesn't result in more records but simply "adds: the TNUM to the CLASS record. The second join multiplies the CLASS records for every record in the ITITLE with equal or higher ranking. The third join eliminates any record for which there isn't a corresponding(based on t2 ranking) INST.